# Web Scraping with JavaScript? JavaScript file I/O? JavaScript iterate through URLs? Automatically load external scripts?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am looking to do some web-scraping, without going through help desk and IT to install and configure Python (I don't have admin rights because I'm an intern).

I have already written the logging functions I need in JavaScript, but I need to extract the data out of the program into a CSV so I can convert to .XLS afterward.

I'm wondering if it's possible for JavaScript to do these things:

1. Can JavaScript write to a file?
2. Can I run external scripts with a click of a button somehow?  i.e. without pasting the code into the console every single page. Or even, perhaps, run external scripts automatically upon page-load?
3. Can I automatically iterate through and load URLs?  The URL details all remain the same, with only an integer value that changes from page to page.

Thanks in advance for any input!!

Comment: Is it possible to do with JavaScript? Yes. But it looks like you're actually asking if it's possible to do with the *browser*. Is that correct?

Comment: yes i was going to attempt to do it in browser.  I guess I'm going to have to look at running a dummy server?

Comment: If you can install/configure a server why can't you just write code?

Comment: what i mean is using node.js or something to run a local server.  but tbh i'm in way over my head here it looks like

Comment: If you want to run NodeJS as a server then why can't you just write the JS code in NodeJS?

Comment: i have less than 0 experience with node.js so i'm going to have to do some research first

Comment: But... you said you wanted to use JS to do this; NodeJS is just a JS runtime and some libraries that will let you do what you said you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you can use javascript to write to file using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) Use the fs module like so.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('file.txt', data_to_write[, options], callback)
```

Refer : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

2) Yes, you can use [puppetter](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to run Headless Chrome scripts

3) Go through the puppeteer documentation and you can find how to load URLs on the browser. Iterate the links and store them in a string and open the page. Then use page.evaluate() to run you code and scrape the contents.

Comment: I just finished this task with nodeJS and pupeteer, should I post my code?  thank you both for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do all those things with JavaScript. No, you can't do all those things with JavaScript *purely in the browser* because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Two things that let you do this (offhand):

- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), which you can download and expand from a zip (doesn't require an installation step). Whether you can do that on your workstation depends on how locked down it is. There are lots of modules available for Node.js for handling the heavy-lifting of web scraping.
- A Java JVM (via its scripting support, though JavaScript scripting hosts for the JVM trail behind in terms of up-to-date JavaScript features). If one isn't already installed, again, you may be able to install one without admin rights, or not, depending.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it with node.js from server-side.

But you'll face the cross-origin problem doing it from HTML page in browser.

So for browser you'll have to make a browser plugin (aka add-on aka extension).